# Using linear algebra to study number theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, prime-factorization, linear-regression, riemann-hypothesis

I've posted [a paper on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.05959) that outlines a linear algebra approach to number theory.

Specifically, I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to draw connections between the factorization matrix (Def. 4 and 6) and [the Redheffer matrix or the Mertens function](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3701)? Does this allow to come up with an alternative formulation of the Riemann hypothesis (Eq. 55 and 56)?
2. Is it possible to evaluate the difference $\pi(x) - \mathrm{Li}(x)$ using the matrix algebra expression for $\pi(x)$ (Eq. 44)? How can the inverse of the factorization matrix (Eq. 39) be further developped to help in this respect?

Answers to either one of the questions are appreciated!

Comment: Is this just a promotion for the arXiv publication? Seriously, starting with "just a neuroscientist with an interest in statistics" and then jumping to the Riemann hypothesis might for many make the paper appear not worth reading ...

Comment: I wouldn't call it "promotion" as there's no possibility for me to earn something with it. Would you suggest to remove the neuroscience/statistics reference in order not to distract from the subject matter? If you believe that linear algebra can help to study arithmetic functions, it's worth a read.

Comment: Certainly it's consider good style to make questions and answers self-contained instead of making the reader follow links or read papers.

Comment: Hm... I didn't do that as it's a rather broad and open question. Would you suggest to state the main theorems from the paper and then proceed with more specific questions?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I hope that you don't find rude this my comment, but I don't agree with your critic about the profession of the user asking here. If I understand well the user tell us the profession because need help or a different point of view about the work. Of course critics help to see the things from different view point, but the point in site is if you can help with an answer, in this case about the approach, the mathematics, of the paper. Good day.

Comment: @JoramSoch What Markus meant was that you should include equations and and definitions that you refer from the paper in the question.

Comment: @user243301 I don't find your comment rude and I didn't want to criticize the OP for his profession.

Comment: Then was my interpretation, I'm sorry @HagenvonEitzen